# C++ How to make a function overload that accepts class functions as argument

Tags: c++

I'm using ALGLIB to run a LBFGS minimization of a given function. To do so I need to use the following statement:

```
alglib::minlbfgsoptimize(state, FunctionToOptimizeHere)
```

Here is one declaration of alglib::minlbfgsoptimize provided in the ALGLIB package:

```
void minlbfgsoptimize(minlbfgsstate &state,
void (*grad)(const real_1d_array &x, double &func, real_1d_array &grad, void *ptr),
void  (*rep)(const real_1d_array &x, double func, void *ptr) = NULL,
void *ptr = NULL,
const xparams _xparams = alglib::xdefault);
```

So when I create my function outside of any class as

```
void function(const alglib::real_1d_array& x, double& func, alglib::real_1d_array& grad, void* ptr)
```

It works fine but the problem is that I need to use it on a function that is inside a class it doesn't work. The arguments do not match because my function is now a:

```
void MyClass::Myfunction(const alglib::real_1d_array& x, double& func, alglib::real_1d_array& grad, void* ptr)
```

I can't figure it out how to overload minlbfgsoptimize to accept my (inside of a class) function. Can anybody help me with that? Thank you

Comment: If the inside-the-class function is called `void Foo::Frobnicate();` then make a freestanding thunking function outside the class called `void ThunkFooFrobnicate(Foo* foo) { foo->Frobnicate(); }` and pass the `ThunkFooFrobnicate` function in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, your library provides a way to pass context to the callback. You need an intermediate non-member or static member function (sometimes known as a "trampoline"). Something along these lines:

```
class MyClass {
  void DoActualWork(const alglib::real_1d_array& x, ...);
  static void Trampoline(const alglib::real_1d_array& x, ..., void* ptr) {
    static_cast<MyClass*>(ptr)->DoActualWork(x, ...);
  }
};
```

You would then call it this way:

```
MyClass myObject;
alglib::minlbfgsoptimize(state, MyClass::Trampoline, nullptr, &myObject);
```

Note how a `MyClass` pointer is passed to `minlbfgsoptimize`, in `void* ptr` parameter. The library then forwards it along to the callback, which recovers the original `MyClass` pointer and calls a member function through it.

Comment: I've never seen that before, pretty cool. I'll definitely try that right now!